# Web Application works fine in Eclipse but intellji cannot find path

Tags: eclipse, spring, intellij-idea

I have created a web application using jHipster and it works just fine in Eclipse, however I get the following error when I try to run it in my browser:

```
[DEBUG] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /
[DEBUG] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/]
[DEBUG] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /error
[DEBUG] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/error]
```

I am so confused I do not even know what to post to debug the solution. If anyone has ever encountered this issue with share how you solved it.

Comment: How do you package the application (Gradle, Maven...)? How do you run the configuration in the IDEs? Did you check if there are differences in the runtime classpath?

Comment: @dunni Springboot and I selected Eclipse import. I used the same class path as eclipse.

Comment: try to set `Working directory` to module dir.

Comment: @Meo I looked at the module and everything looks fine from what I can tell. Now I am having database connection issues. However everything still works great in Eclipse. Looks like I have to stick with it. I really wanted to give Intellji a shot.

Comment: do this for the configuration you use to run it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5638830/685796